# Output Zend Form To Array of Key => Value

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like a Zend_Form object to be output as essentially

array('name' => 'input username in db', 'description' => 'description thats in the database');

so far If I do

print_r((array) $form);

I get:

```
{"\u0000*\u0000_attribs":{"name":"add","enctype":"multipart\/form-data","method":"post"},"\u0000*\u0000_decorators":{"FormElements":{"decorator":"FormElements","options":null},"HtmlTag":{"decorator":"HtmlTag","options":{"tag":"dl","class":"zend_form"}},"Form":{"decorator":"Form","options":null}},"\u0000*\u0000_defaultDisplayGroupClass":"Zend_Form_DisplayGroup","\u0000*\u0000_description":null,"\u0000*\u0000_disableLoadDefaultDecorators":false,"\u0000*\u0000_displayGroupPrefixPaths":[],"\u0000*\u0000_displayGroups":[],"\u0000*\u0000_elementDecorators":null,"\u0000*\u0000_elementPrefixPaths":[],"\u0000*\u0000_elements":{"name":{"helper":"formText"},"name_url":{"helper":"formText"},"description":{"helper":"formTextarea","rows":"10"}
```

etcetc, alot of Zend storage

If I do:

```
    $form = new Form_Administration_Movie_Add();
    $elements = $form->getElements();

    foreach($elements as $key => $element) {
     echo $key;
    }
```

I get a list of the fields, however I cannot do $element->getValue() as I just get 0 or 1 and no the actual data.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = $form->getValues();
```

Does this work? :)

**Edit:** You might need to use either `$form->isValid($_POST)` or `$form->populate($_POST)` before calling the `getValues()` method.